# What is a good Stack Exchange site to ask this question about general programming language tutorials and examples?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question about programming tutorials / examples that I want to ask, but I don't want to get down votes doing so:

> When you are learning how to program in a certain language or with a particular framework, it is very useful to have an actual real-world example of that project being used somewhere in the open source community.
>
> Has any stumbled across a particular updated website or online resource that provides OSS source code links (like GitHub, SourceForge, etc.) to programming languages / frameworks?
>
> This would be especially useful for software engineering professionals who need to learn a new language/framework and want to skip the "Hello World" and get right to something useful.

What Stack Exchange site is the best for this particular question?

Comment: From its help page Open Data looks as though it might be suitable https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic although I do not use the site myself so cannot confirm that.

Comment: The short sad answer is: nowhere. This is ultimately a "[shopping question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)", and as such people will supply their own *favorite* answers, not the *right* answer (because there isn't one), and voting devolves into a petty popularity contest, not an evaluation of expertise.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackexchange.com/sites first?

Comment: neat! i had no idea that existed

Comment: yep it is indeed. that sucks, too bad SE can't be used as a recommendation engine. forget it then.

Comment: I am very appreciative of the person who recommended opendata for this. Got a great answer there, and no one was a jerk and -1'd my very reasonable question because of semantics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there would be very few if any sites on the network which could support that question.  We have a tendency to simply *not* support questions which ask us to provide links or resources to external sites, since we trust you to be able to perform the appropriate $searchEngine searches you need to in order to arrive at other examples.

When you have a concrete problem to actually *solve* and are having trouble with your solution (note:  "where do I begin" isn't an actual problem, that's more of a mission statement), then Stack Overflow *could* help.

I'd like to stress:

## Do not post a question looking for resources on Stack Overflow.

### You're going to have a *bad* time with the site if you do that. Please, don't.

But, when you have a concrete question about something you encountered when attempting to go through an example, then you *might* be able to ask over there.

Comment: Yep i knew from past experience not to dare adding that to stackoverflow. the onslaught of -1's would have been blinding

Comment: Well @NicholasDiPiazza, I don't want you treating it like a situation where it's too hazardous to go and post something on Stack Overflow.  Just be cognizant as to what the expectations of content are over there and you'll largely avoid said onslaught.